# TestFlight release validation issue

Tags: app-store

I am trying to upload a build for internal testing, and after Archiving when I try to validate or distribute the build, an error is getting thrown as follows

When I validate the archived build, I do get an error as follow, but couldn't identify the specific reason.

The app references non-public selectors in Payload/IA DN.app/IA DN: _setWidth: (ID: 44047531-efe4-4ff0-911d-75b75d59d0a6)

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.